# Sqoop : import data from Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I try to use Sqoop to import data from an Oracle DB.

I have placed the Oracle JDBC Driver (ojdbc6.jar) into SQOOP_HOME/lib.

My JDK is 1.6 version.

Here is my query :

```
sqoop import --hive-import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@<ip_server>:1521/db --table ENTITE --username username --password password
```

But, when i launch the command, i get this error :

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver
```

I don't understand why Sqoop can't connect to my db server.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If your using sqoop 1.4.2 assuming based on ojdbc6.jar above then see comments about the --driver usage from Kathleen here as it shouldn't be required:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-457

With sqoop 1.4.2 and dropping ojdbc6.jar into my sqoop/lib this string works w/HDP 1.3 and MapR 2.0:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=myhost)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=myservice)))" \
--username USER --table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME --hive-import --hive-table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME \
--num-mappers 1 --verbose -P \
```

If you have access to mysql and or sql server, etc. test those too and make sure your lib directory is getting picked up.  SQL Server is / was supposed to be in sqoop 1.4, but the docs and attempting to use it proved otherwise:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774 - here is what you want for sql server testing.

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the oracle jdbc driver inside sqoop lib directory

Comment: Links? and where to put?

Comment: I am sorry I can't remember that now. It was long ago.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the oracle connector jar file and copy that jar file to lib folder of Sqoop.

The jar file can be downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

copy this jar file to your Sqoop lib folder (/usr/lib/sqoop/lib)

And run the sqoop command.

Comment: My bad, forgot to mention the jar name below link will get you " http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html "

Answer (score 0):

Check your sqoop classpath by adding echo and make sure your driver is on the classpath. Same problem I have faced and resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

look at the error message: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver 
You need to type oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver with high register "O", since java is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

The error says that sqoop can't load oracle driver class as there is no ojdbc driver jar file in its path.First, You have to add ojdbc driver jar to lib folder of your sqoop home. Please download it here

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadojdbc6jar.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

oracle ojdbc6.jar needs to be copied to sqoop/lib directory to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

You can state the oracle driver you use like so

`sqoop import --hive-import --driver oracle.jdbc.driver.oracledriver --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@<ip_server>:1521/db --table ENTITE --username username --password password`

Comment: thanks for your response, but i get the same error when i try with this option :-(

Answer (score -1):

sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=hostip)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=servicename)))" --username user --password pwd --table schema.tablename --hive-import --num-mappers 1 --verbose -P

Comment: Provide a bit of explanation and this is a much better answer!